# Can't import Selenium package

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, site-packages

I've definitely downloaded `Selenium` but why can't I import `Selenium`??

PATH of `Selenium` is `C:\Users\공용장비-02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\selenium`

[image]

Comment: Are you using venv o system python? Check on your python envoiremente 'pip freeze | grep -i selenium' to know if its installed, else pip install selenium

Comment: @Wonka What is `venu o system`?

Comment: Python virtual environment

Comment: @Wonka Actually I find `Selenium` but i can't import it.. do you know why it is?

Comment: did you download the package and configure it manually? or did you use a package manager?

Comment: @M3trix I think I didn't use a package manger

Comment: so maybe you made a mistake while configuring your package or it's not compatible or something else. try to install it again using a package manager. I hope it works.